# plivo send message not working

Tags: php, plivo

I have used plivo for send message. 
I dont get any proper help or example,so if can anyone provide that then thats better.
I have tried https://github.com/plivo/plivo-examples-php (`send_sms_from_browser.php`) but that not working for me.

anyway I am trying to run demo  `https://github.com/plivo/plivo-examples-php (send_sms_from_browser.php)`

and getting following output but message not receiving on my mobile.so please anyone can help me?

```
Sent Message info:

To: +91********** (i have added my mobile number here,so is that right?)
From: +91********** (i have added my second mobile number here,so is that right?)
Message: Message Text

Array
(
    [status] => 202
    [response] => Array
        (
            [api_id] => ***********
            [message] => message(s) queued
            [message_uuid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ***************
                )

        )

)

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/test/plivo-examples-php-master/send_sms_from_browser.php on line 38

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/test/plivo-examples-php-master/send_sms_from_browser.php on line 39


Message status: Sent
```

**Updated:**

Its working now, its due to my number is in DND. now how to resolve that? is there any option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but to bad mistake here that plivo not working with DND numbers, i tried non DND number and its working

Answer (score 0):

Your "From" number might be invalid. Is it a number that you purchased from plivo? They don't let you use a number unless its a number you purchased from them.

If thats not the case then maybe "Message" should be "Text". Thats what its called in the REST API docs.

Does the examples come with a plivo auth_id and auth_token?

Comment: I have added my own auth_id and auth_token in example, to run that example have to add so many pear files